# how to get stdin and stdout of a running c program

Tags: java, c

i want to code a manager program in java which will execute a c program and can read it's input stream and write to output stream.

the client will request c exe then server will handle it's request like following :

1. the manager program will execute.
2. it'll execute a c program.
3. can send c program's output to browser.(input stream).
4. should be able to accept input from browser and supply to c program.

i have tried executing c code using Runtime and Process. but it gives exception

```
---------------------------
16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem
---------------------------
Error while setting up environment for the application. Choose 'Close' to terminate the application.
---------------------------
Close   
---------------------------
```

help?

code : 
    import java.io.*;

```
class Dev
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dev.exe");
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        // from her i'll do the stuff but it gives error.

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print("\n\n\t Error : "+e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to show us code if you want help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a program by creating a class that implements `Runnable`, then passing it a `Process`, which is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659933/377628). The answer there also describes how to get the process's output in an `InputStream`. As for passing in some input, this can be done by piping a string in the command line. On the `Process`-making line from that answer, you can add:

```
//...
String someInput, command; // Set these to the appropriate values.
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo \"" + someInput + "\"|" + command);
//...
```

This will pipe the value of `someInput` to `command`. This is based on the command line and is technically platform specific, but should work without changes on Linux, OS X, and Windows.