# Common system environment for multiple processes in JAVA

Tags: java, system, environment

Like in the title - I have a processes (pool of paths to scripts to be more specific) that I want to start up using single shareable environment. Scripts will be started in a sequence and each entity may affect the input environment for another entity. When the whole pool is fired up I would like to retrieve the output environment.

Any ideas? Thaaaanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bunch of Executors to me.

Comment: Just start processes from java and read stdout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659796/run-external-program-from-java-read-output-allow-interruption

Comment: What stdout has to do with the system environment?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass env variable when running a process from Java

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
...
```

Comment: I Do not get it... and how am I suppose to execute multiple programs in sequence and share the environment using ProcessBuilder

Comment: Yes, if your want to run processes from Java and pass an env var to them you need to do it this way, or I misunderstood the question

Comment: Ok so I understand you want the env each time to be retrieved from pb to overwrite the environment of next pb in queue. If it's so I was hopeing for a bit elegant way.

Comment: You can reuse pb eg pb.command("command1"); pb.start(); then pb.command("command2"); pb.start(); it will run 2 different processes

Comment: Oh, this I didn't know. I thought this is a one time instance... Thanks